# Menu toggle effect and submenus hover area

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, padding

I am having some troubles in styling the top dropdown menu [here](http://bit.ly/UQM7Ff) so that it creates a toggle effect. I am using padding to delimit the hover area but then there is no chance I can hover over the submenus.

```
#topmenu {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20pt;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `z-index: larger-number` to `#topmenu` to make sure the menu is always on the top level, so it can be hovered.

css transform will change the z-index order. you used it on the `h2`. it covered the submenu.

in actully, change nothing, but scroll down your page. you'll find the hover issue on menu gone.

#### Demo for **rotate element** covered **absolute element**:

http://jsfiddle.net/rainthinks/xswrg/

the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/rainthinks/xswrg/1/

some refs:

- http://daneden.me/2012/04/css-transforms-and-z-index/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/

Comment: Hi, I am still having troubles with this. I can't figure out how to do the proper submenu hover (see [here](http://bit.ly/VJnZCn) by hovering LO SPETTACOLO, then GLI AUTORI). The submenu is always off...

Answer (score 0):

Make the padding and margins 0; and also give the code so that I could understand any other problem.

Comment: I just edited the first post. Also, according to your suggestion, for which selector I need to put the padding and margin set to zero?